# C# WPF How to set Property setter method dynamically?

Tags: c#, dynamic, methods, properties, setter

I've been searching around but I just can't seem to find what I'm looking for, so I'll give it a go here.

Situation:
I have the class MainWindow and MainWindowData. In MainWindowData are only public properties defined with the attribute UpdateGUI.

```
public class UpdateGUI : Attribute { }

public class MainWindowData
{
    [UpdateGUI]
    public string TESTVAR { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to add a method to each property's setter method in MainWindowData. More specific:

```
void OnPropertyChanged(String PropertyName);
```

I figured I'd fetch all UpdateGUI properties in the MainWindow constructor, and then somehow add another method to it, but this is where I'm stuck.
I use this code to fetch all properties, which works:

```
List<PropertyInfo> properties = (from pi in typeof(MainWindowData).GetProperties()
                                 where pi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(UpdateGUI), false).Any()
                                 select pi).ToList();
```

This gives me a nice list of all properties that I have to update.

So the question is: how can I make it so that the properties dynamically get transformed from:

```
[UpdateGUI]
public string TESTVAR { get; set; }
```

to:

```
[UpdateGUI]
private string _TESTVAR;
public string TESTVAR { 
    get {
        return _TESTVAR;
    }
    set {
        _TESTVAR = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("TESTVAR");
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help! It will be highly appreciated :)

Greetings

Comment: +1 Interesting question, will be nice to see what comes out of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for has been solved in the concept of Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP).

One example is [in PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions#ui), (Also, [see details here](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/notifypropertychanged)) which lets you write your data/viewmodel classes like this:

```
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
public class Shape
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}

public class Rectangle : Shape
{
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
}
```

If you don't like PostSharp, I'm sure the other AOP frameworks out there has similar functionality.

**EDIT**

I just found [NotifyPropertyWeaver](http://code.google.com/p/notifypropertyweaver/) which does this for you without requiring a full AOP framework.

It uses the Mono.Cecil stuff to inject notification code during compilation and is installable either through NuGet (this is what I did) or from the project web site.

By default, it doesn't even require attributes, (it automatically figures out which properties and classes need change notification) but you can be explicit also, like so:

```
[NotifyProperty]
public int FooBar { get; set; }
```

One nice feature I found in it was the possibility to declare dependencies between properties. In this case, `RaisePropertyChanged("FoobarTimesTwo")` will be called whenever FooBar changes.

```
[DependsOn("FooBar")]
public int FoobarTimesTwo
{
    get { return FooBar * 2; }
}
```

Comment: +1 interesting piece of work. the links to details provides coding ideas if one would like to do this him/herself.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, that is exactly what I need. Sadly it isn't free to use, but maybe I can figure it out or find some other AOP framework.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to AOP frameworks like PostSharp there are also such things as:

[Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil)

With that tool you can take an assembly, modify it's code and save it back

There are some articles of LinFu about AOP which may help

[LinFu Articles on CodeProject](http://www.pnpguidance.net/Post/LinFuArticlesCodeProjectWellWorthReading.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The open source framework [ImpromptuInterface.MVVM](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageMVVM) uses the C# 4.0 dynamic features to add automatic properties that support property changed. It's ImpromptuViewModel works like an ExpandoObject but also has other features to help with MVVM.